# A cursor with the name 'tds_cur' does not exist

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm maintaining a system for HR and timekeeping. We have migrated its server from 2008 to 2016. While in 2008 version, the stored procedure is working properly. When migrated to 2016, the same stored procedure without any modification throws the error "A cursor with the name 'tds_cur' does not exist."

This is my stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [SYSADM].[tds] 
    @dt_from DATETME, 
    @dt_to DATETME, 
    @as_depcode VARCHAR(5), 
    @as_seccode VARCHAR(5), 
    @as_subsec VARCHAR(5),
    @as_empcode VARCHAR(5), 
    @as_aproved CHAR(1), 
    @as_dsaproved CHAR(1), 
    @as_userid VARCHAR(8), 
    @dt_rcvdfrom DATETIME,
    @dt_rcvdto DATETIME
AS 
BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE #tmp180
    (
         tds_tdsno CHAR(8), 
         tds_dateout DATETIME NULL, 
         tds_datelate DATETIME NULL,
         tds_criteria CHAR(1), 
         tds_employee CHAR(150), 
         tds_reason CHAR(100) NULL,
         tds_datefiled DATETIME NULL, 
         tds_dateaprvd DATETIME NULL, 
         tds_aprovedby CHAR(5) NULL,
         tds_dtfrom DATETIME NULL, 
         tds_dtto DATETIME NULL, 
         tds_aproved CHAR(1) NULL, 
         tds_dsaprved CHAR(1) NULL,
         tds_userid CHAR(8)
    )

    DECLARE @s_tdsno CHAR(8), @s_criteria CHAR(1), 
            @s_lname CHAR(50), @s_fname CHAR(50), @s_mname CHAR(50),
            @s_empname CHAR(150), @s_reason CHAR(100), 
            @s_aprvdby CHAR(5), @s_empcode CHAR(5),
            @dt_out DATETIME, @dt_late DATETIME,
            @dt_filed DATETIME, @dt_aprvd DATETIME, 
            @s_dep CHAR(5), @s_sec CHAR(5)

    IF @as_aproved <> null and @dt_from <> null and @dt_rcvdfrom is null
    BEGIN
        DECLARE tds_cur CURSOR FOR
        SELECT tds_tdsno, tds_dateout, tds_datelate, tds_criteria, tds_employee, tds_reason, tds_datefiled, tds_dateaprvd, tds_aprovedby, emp_depcode, emp_seccode
        FROM TDS, employee
        WHERE tds_employee = emp_code and emp_depcode like ltrim(@as_depcode) and emp_seccode like ltrim(@as_seccode) and
        emp_subseccode like ltrim(@as_subsec) and tds_employee like ltrim(@as_empcode) and
        tds_datefiled >= @dt_from and tds_datefiled <= @dt_to and (tds_dateaprvd <> null or tds_dateaprvd <> '')
    END
else if @as_aproved <> null and @dt_from <> null and @dt_rcvdfrom <> null
    BEGIN
        DECLARE tds_cur CURSOR FOR
        SELECT tds_tdsno, tds_dateout, tds_datelate, tds_criteria, tds_employee, tds_reason, tds_datefiled, tds_dateaprvd, tds_aprovedby, emp_depcode, emp_seccode
        FROM TDS, employee
        WHERE tds_employee = emp_code and emp_depcode like ltrim(@as_depcode) and emp_seccode like ltrim(@as_seccode) and
        emp_subseccode like ltrim(@as_subsec) and tds_employee like ltrim(@as_empcode) and
        tds_datefiled >= @dt_from and tds_datefiled <= @dt_to and (tds_dateaprvd <> null or tds_dateaprvd <> '') and 
        tds_rcvdte >= @dt_rcvdfrom and tds_rcvdte <= @dt_rcvdto
    END

else if @as_aproved <> null and @dt_from is null and @dt_rcvdfrom <> null
    BEGIN
        DECLARE tds_cur CURSOR FOR
        SELECT tds_tdsno, tds_dateout, tds_datelate, tds_criteria, tds_employee, tds_reason, tds_datefiled, tds_dateaprvd, tds_aprovedby, emp_depcode, emp_seccode
        FROM TDS, employee
        WHERE tds_employee = emp_code and emp_depcode like ltrim(@as_depcode) and emp_seccode like ltrim(@as_seccode) and
        emp_subseccode like ltrim(@as_subsec) and tds_employee like ltrim(@as_empcode) and
        (tds_dateaprvd <> null or tds_dateaprvd <> '') and tds_rcvdte >= @dt_rcvdfrom and tds_rcvdte <= @dt_rcvdto
--      tds_datefiled >= @dt_from and tds_datefiled <= @dt_to and 
    END


IF @as_dsaproved <> null and @dt_from <> null and @dt_rcvdfrom is null
    BEGIN
        DECLARE tds_cur CURSOR FOR
        SELECT tds_tdsno, tds_dateout, tds_datelate, tds_criteria, tds_employee, tds_reason, tds_datefiled, tds_dateaprvd, tds_aprovedby,
         emp_depcode, emp_seccode
        FROM TDS, employee
        WHERE tds_employee = emp_code and emp_depcode like ltrim(@as_depcode) and emp_seccode like ltrim(@as_seccode) and
            emp_subseccode like ltrim(@as_subsec) and tds_employee like ltrim(@as_empcode) and
            tds_datefiled >= @dt_from and tds_datefiled <= @dt_to and (tds_dateaprvd = null or tds_dateaprvd = '')
    END
else IF @as_dsaproved <> null and @dt_from <> null  and @dt_rcvdfrom <> null
    BEGIN
        DECLARE tds_cur CURSOR FOR
        SELECT tds_tdsno, tds_dateout, tds_datelate, tds_criteria, tds_employee, tds_reason, tds_datefiled, tds_dateaprvd, tds_aprovedby,
         emp_depcode, emp_seccode
        FROM TDS, employee
        WHERE tds_employee = emp_code and emp_depcode like ltrim(@as_depcode) and emp_seccode like ltrim(@as_seccode) and
            emp_subseccode like ltrim(@as_subsec) and tds_employee like ltrim(@as_empcode) and
            tds_datefiled >= @dt_from and tds_datefiled <= @dt_to and (tds_dateaprvd = null or tds_dateaprvd = '') and
            tds_rcvdte >= @dt_rcvdfrom and tds_rcvdte <= @dt_rcvdto
    END
else IF @as_dsaproved <> null and @dt_from is null  and @dt_rcvdfrom <> null
    BEGIN
        DECLARE tds_cur CURSOR FOR
        SELECT tds_tdsno, tds_dateout, tds_datelate, tds_criteria, tds_employee, tds_reason, tds_datefiled, tds_dateaprvd, tds_aprovedby,
         emp_depcode, emp_seccode
        FROM TDS, employee
        WHERE tds_employee = emp_code and emp_depcode like ltrim(@as_depcode) and emp_seccode like ltrim(@as_seccode) and
            emp_subseccode like ltrim(@as_subsec) and tds_employee like ltrim(@as_empcode) and
            (tds_dateaprvd = null or tds_dateaprvd = '') and tds_rcvdte >= @dt_rcvdfrom and tds_rcvdte <= @dt_rcvdto
--          tds_datefiled >= @dt_from and tds_datefiled <= @dt_to and 
    END
OPEN tds_cur

FETCH NEXT FROM tds_cur INTO @s_tdsno, @dt_out, @dt_late, @s_criteria, @s_empcode, @s_reason,
                @dt_filed, @dt_aprvd,@s_aprvdby, @s_dep, @s_sec
WHILE @@fetch_status = 0


BEGIN

    SELECT @s_lname= emp_lname FROM employee WHERE emp_code = @s_empcode
    SELECT @s_fname = emp_fname FROM employee WHERE emp_code = @s_empcode
    SELECT @s_mname = emp_midname FROM employee WHERE emp_code = @s_empcode

    SELECT @s_empname = rtrim(@s_lname)+', '+rtrim(@s_fname)+' '+SUBSTRING(rtrim(@s_mname),1,1)+'.'

/*  if @dt_from is null 
        select @dt_from = @dt_rcvdfrom

    if @dt_to is null 
        select @dt_to = @dt_rcvdto */

    INSERT INTO #tmp180 VALUES(@s_tdsno, @dt_out, @dt_late, @s_criteria, @s_empname, @s_reason,
                    @dt_filed,@dt_aprvd, @s_aprvdby, @dt_from, @dt_to, @as_aproved, 
                    @as_dsaproved, @as_userid)

    FETCH NEXT FROM tds_cur INTO @s_tdsno, @dt_out, @dt_late, @s_criteria, @s_empcode, @s_reason,
                    @dt_filed, @dt_aprvd, @s_aprvdby, @s_dep, @s_sec
END

--CLOSE tds_cur
DEALLOCATE tds_cur

SELECT * FROM #tmp180   


END
```

And this is how i execute the stored procedure:

```
EXEC tds  @dt_from = '12/01/2019 00:00:00', 
@dt_to = '12/31/2019 23:00:00', 
@as_depcode = null,@as_seccode = null, @as_subsec = null,@as_empcode = null, @as_aproved =null,@as_dsaproved =null, @as_userid='USER',@dt_rcvdfrom = null, @dt_rcvdto = null
```

and the result is:

> Msg 16916, Level 16, State 1, Procedure tds, Line 70 [Batch Start Line 0]
>   A cursor with the name 'tds_cur' does not exist.
>
> Msg 16916, Level 16, State 1, Procedure tds, Line 83 [Batch Start Line 0]
>   A cursor with the name 'tds_cur' does not exist.
>
> Msg 16916, Level 16, State 1, Procedure tds, Line 111 [Batch Start Line 0]
>   A cursor with the name 'tds_cur' does not exist.

I know cursor is not the preferable method for this, but there is no time for rewriting the code.

I tried putting deallocate in every position possible, outside and inside the loop still, nothing happned.

The server setting for cursor is set to GLOBAL

I'm frustrated because I don't know what else might be the reason for that.

Looking forward for all of your help.

Comment: The problem is probably because the execution did not goes into any one of the `IF` block. And the reason is because you check for `null` value using `<> NULL`. It should be either `is null` or `is not null`

Comment: also, the query can be easily convert to `non-cursor`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use "IS NOT NULL" instead of "<> NULL"

Comment: this became my solution. does the <> operand is different in 2016? the compiler seems okay with it. anyway, thank you sir!

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that your ANSI NULLS settings have changed between 2008 and 2016.

Check the details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-ansi-nulls-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Your quickest way to retain the same behavior as previously might be to add

```
SET ANSI NULLS OFF
```

into the start of the Stored Procedure to set the backward compatibility.

Note that this option will be probably be removed in the future so you then want to look at rewriting your procedure to also remove the cursors.

Comment: this solves the problem, but what is the drawback of this approach? As far as i know that this system that im using will not receive any major update because they are switching to SAP and other software but for the meantime, im want to prepare.

Comment: The drawback is that ANSI_NULLS is required to be set for certain functionality. So long as you avoid that functionality, your system will work **FOR NOW**. You are using a completely unsupported version of sql server - that should be sufficient warning for anyone.  And TBH - this is just code that should never have been written and used in a production system even in 2008.

Comment: If you follow the ANSI NULL settings on each of you procedures, functions, databases etc in the old system then you should expect to see the same behavior.


In addition, I would ensure that the new database is set to 100 compatibility level to also ensure it behaves the same as the old one in terms of query engine behavior and cardinality estimator.


If this is a temporary solution, then I would be willing to accept the risk of the ANSI NULL settings - AS LONG AS I HAD COPIED OVER EACH ONE FROM SOURCE.